# Starling - how do you know that had to touch the figure?

Tags: actionscript-3

Sorry for Broken English - Google translator.
There is an object of complex shape, check as I touched the object or not?
What is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [starling docs](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/events/TouchEvent.html)

> To process user input from a touch screen or the mouse, you have to register an event listener for events of the type TouchEvent.

When the event listener function is called, you know that the object has been clicked / touched.

Comment: I agree with you, but reacts rectangular area, and I need to determine what exactly had to touch the object